# Which article to use: 'the' / 'a'

Tags: articles

I saw this news on the site, I would like to understand why this or that article is used. Grammarly also highlights the error " ̶a̶  credit"
 The first option was used on the site.

1. > Pete Rosenberg claims G.O.O.D. Music “forgot” to give him a credit for his melody on ***the*** hook.
2. > Pete Rosenberg claims G.O.O.D. Music “forgot” to give him a credit for his melody on ***a*** hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "hook" is a catchy part of a song meant to draw attention and stick in people's mind. Usually a song only has one hook, so the definite article is used to refer to *the* hook for this particular song.

The "melody on the hook" is the melody that plays during the hook.

Comment: But " melody on the hook" doesn't seem to make sense, so I can't see how it applies to the example.

Comment: @user3169 Does my edit help?

Comment: Now I understand it. If the phrase is an idiom you might add that, which automatically eliminates using "a"

Comment: @user3169 It *can* be "a hook", just not in this sentence. It depends on which article any noun would take in the context.